# Populate SELECT OPTION from INPUT field jQuery

Tags: jquery

I been using `SELECT OPTION` to feed `INPUT` fields using jQuery, but am stuck on how I can feed a `SELECT OPTION` from a couple of `INPUT` fields

My form

```
<form>
    <input type="text" name="box1" id="box1"/>
    <input type="text" name="box2" id="box2"/>
    <select name="allinputtogether">
        <option value="pullthevaluefrominputbox1">pullthevaluefrominputbox1</option>
        <option value="pullthevaluefrominputbox2">pullthevaluefrominputbox2</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

How can I get the value that the user has input in the `INPUT` (box1 & box2) fields after input to then show within the `SELECT OPTION` for the user then to select either for the next stage of the form using jQuery?

I use this jQuery below to take the option selected in a SELECT to feed into an INPUT field, but how can I reverse the situation?

```
<select name="MySELECT" id="MySELECT">
   <option value="1">MyDBfeedsthisSelect</option>

   $(function() {
        $("#MySELECT").change(function(){
            var TheSelect= $('option:selected', this).attr('whichselectionoption');
            $('#theselector').val(TheSelect);                
        });
    });

<input type='hidden' id="theselector" name="theselector" value=""/>
```

Comment: Can you elaborate?? code, goal....

Comment: Please be more clear, it's difficult to understand what your problem is.

Comment: How do you want to get the box1 value as an option in there?  After typing? after losing focus? After hitting enter?

Comment: After the user has input within the `INPUT` field it then shows within the `SELECT`

Comment: How is it possible to set the `OPTION VALUE` on the `SELECT` to that of what was typed in the `INPUT` field

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code :

http://jsfiddle.net/v7f1xetb/

```
$("#box1").on("keyup",function(){
    $('select[name="allinputtogether"]  option[value="'+$(this).val()+'"]').prop('selected', true);
});
```

It selects the option that has the same value as the text entered in the first input.
If the option doesn't exist, it does nothing.

Comment: Thanks, the `SELECT OPTION` value doesnt change when anything is input to the `INPUT` fields, this valuefrombox1 or valuefrombox2 remains

Comment: @539 Yes, it only changes if you write `valuefrombox1` or `valuefrombox2` in the first input. That's what I understood from your question.

Comment: Ah ok, No I want to be able to type anything in the `INPUT` boxes but this then feed the `SELECT OPTIONS`

Comment: @539  Then you need also a button to validate, else how the script could know you have finished typing your new value ? If this is ok with a button, I'll modify my script.

Comment: When I feed the `SELECT` to an `INPUT` else where on the form I use OnChange() within the `SELECT` is there something similar for using it on `INPUT` to `SELECT`?

Comment: So if type Hello World in box1 then how does it show as an option within the SELECT?

Comment: I've tried this but the SELECT is blank `$('input[name="box1"]', function(key, value) {$('#allinputtogether')
.append($("<option></option>").attr("value",key).text(value));});`